# Live video transcoding in JavaScript and DASH

Tags: video-streaming, mpeg-dash, transcoding

I would like to know if there is a library or code sample that allows MPEG DASH playback in javascript and at the same time transcoding of MP4 video segments.

Or if it is possible to perform MP4 video transcoding using JavaScript ideally without API call to backend server.

Eg: This is a sample manifest (CORS allows all origins)

https://d2hlq0qb3sj1r1.cloudfront.net/assets/LGORYXTESTS_S92C_T05_20200603_134503/manifest.mpd

Answer (score 0):

There are many libraries that allow playback, as I am sure you are aware - most of the open source HTMNL5 players will usually support DASH.

DASH streams already provide multiple bit rates typically, so if the provided ones are good enough for your use you can simply modify one of these open libraries to stream just the resolution(s) you want.

If you actually need to transcode on the browser itself then there are javascript ffmpeg ports that will run in a browser - a well supported example:

- https://github.com/Kagami/ffmpeg.js/

Transcoding requires a lot of processing typically so it will either hog resources or run slowly, or quite possibly both as you probably know.